# Tester/Doer pattern: Assume the caller conforms to the pattern or be defensive and repeat the check?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

Assume a simple class that implements the Tester/Doer pattern:

```
public class FooCommandHandler : ICommandHandler
{
    public bool CanHandle(object command)
    {
        return command is FooCommand;
    }

    public void Handle(object command)
    {
        var fooCommand = (FooCommand)command;
        // Do something with fooCommand
    }
}
```

Now, if someone doesn't conform to the pattern and calls `Handle` without verifying the command via `CanHandle`, the code in `Handle` throws an exception.

However, depending on the actual implementation of `Handle` this can be a whole range of different exceptions.

The following implementation would check `CanHandle` again in `Handle` and throw a *descriptive* exception:

```
public void Handle(object command)
{
    if(!CanHandle(command))
        throw new TesterDoerPatternUsageViolationException("Please call CanHandle first");

    // actual implementation of handling the command.
}
```

This has the advantage that the exception is very descriptive.
It has the disadvantage that `CanHandle` is called twice for "good" clients.

Is there a consensus on which variation should be used?

Comment: What's the point of this pattern?  What do you gain over specifically typing `Handle()` so that it only takes a `FooCommand`?

Comment: @Bobson: This is useful in scenarios where you have many implementations of `ICommandHandler` for different commands. All those handlers are registered at a central location (the command dispatcher). It iterates over all registered commands and calls `Handle` only on those that `CanHandle` the current command. You can't implement something like this with generics, because you wouldn't be able to put them in a list.

Comment: What about declaring `ICommandHandler<T> : ICommandHandler`, storing as `List<ICommandHandler> commands`, and retrieving with `commands.Where(x => x is ICommandHandler<FooCommand>)`?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth This is something that C#'s unsophisticated type system handles really badly, in my opinion. You can't look up the handlers for a message without unsafe casts. It's frustrating because it _seems_ like a very simple and common use case. (Languages with better type systems - those with type classes - can handle it in a type-safe way with fewer moving parts.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can't guarantee that `Handle` is always given something it can handle, then you have no choice but to repeat the check by calling `CanHandle` from `Handle`.

That doesn't mean you always have to incur the double check penalty. If you put the call to `CanHandle` in an `Assert` statement, then suitable compiler options can ensure that it is only run in debug builds and removed from release builds.

That way developers get slapped on the wrist when getting it wrong, while production code doesn't have to worry about the overhead. One caveat: you need to have a strong (unit) test suite in place to ensure that all calls to Handle are checked by the assertion.

---

Actually, it may be better to avoid the dilemma altogether.

The problem with a class with one method that validates X, and another method then processes X is that you make that class hugely dependent on its clients and you need to take steps to ensure that people use your class the way it was intended to be used.

If you make `Handle` itself responsible for returning whether the work is acceptable and  will get done, then checking whether the work received is suitable becomes a natural part of how `Handle` should be implemented.

The contract of `Handle` now obviously includes refusing unsuitable work and any tests for implementers of the `ICommandHandler` interface would check that its `Handle` implementation would respond as desired both when handed suitable and when handed unsuitable work.

Using this approach you can do away with the `CanHandle` method from the interface entirely. `CanHandle` may still exist in a class implementing the `ICommandHandler` but if it does, it now is just an implementation detail of that class.

I have written up a slightly more extensive discussion of this here: [Designing your way out of the CanHandle-Handle conundrum](http://softwareonastring.com/619/designing-your-way-out-of-the-canhandle-handle-conundrum)

Comment: Your edit assumes that `CanHandle` and `Handle` are happening at the same time and that for each call to `CanHandle`, there is also a call to `Handle`. However, it is quite possible that `CanHandle` is used to see which commands are available and display them in the UI. The user can then select any number of them to be executed.

Comment: No, @DanielHilgarth, I don't assume that. If you need a way to display available commands in the UI, you can simply provide Handle with a parameter that tells it to actually do the work or not. `Handle` thus remains responsible for deciding whether the work is acceptable and for doing it if it is _and_ it is instructed to do so by its parameters).

Answer (score 0):

I am of the opinion that there's no need for this specific pattern in C#, due to the features of the language.  Here's how I'd implement it:

```
public class CommandManager
{
    private List<ICommandHandler> handlers = new List<ICommandHandler>();

    public void RegisterHandler(ICommandHandler handler) { handlers.Add(handler); }
    public void Dispatch<T>(T command)where T : ICommand { 
        foreach (var handler in handlers.OfType<ICommandHandler<T>>()) handler.Handle(command);
    }
}

public interface ICommand { }
public class FooCommand : ICommand { }
public class BarCommand : ICommand { }


public interface ICommandHandler { }
public interface ICommandHandler<T> : ICommandHandler where T : ICommand
{
    void Handle(T command);
}

public class FooCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<FooCommand>, ICommandHandler<BarCommand>
{
    public void Handle(FooCommand command)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Called FooCommandHandler with FooCommand");
    }
        public void Handle(BarCommand command)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Called FooCommandHandler with BarCommand");
    }
}

public class BarCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<BarCommand>
{

    public void Handle(BarCommand command)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Called BarCommandHandler with BarCommand");
    }
}
```

Executing it would be like this:

```
void Main()
{
    var myCommands = new CommandManager();
    myCommands.RegisterHandler(new FooCommandHandler());
    myCommands.RegisterHandler(new BarCommandHandler());

    myCommands.Dispatch(new FooCommand());
    /* Output:
         Called FooCommandHandler with FooCommand
    */
    myCommands.Dispatch(new BarCommand());
    /* Output:
        Called FooCommandHandler with BarCommand
        Called BarCommandHandler with BarCommand
    */
}
```

`OfType<>()` handles your checking for you - it will automatically filter to only the types which can handle the specified command *and* cast to that type so you can call `Handle()`.  You add only a single `Handle` overload for each specific command it can handle, so you don't have to worry about it being called with an invalid command.

Comment: That isn't really the same. Your code assumes that the only functionality inside `CanHandle` is a type check. But this method really can do anything. For example, it could contain a security check or similar. That scenario couldn't be modeled with your approach.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth That's a valid point - I was just going off of the example you provided.  However, you could reintroduce the `CanHandle` function as `bool CanHandle(T command)` and add a `.Where(x => x.CanHandle(command))` to the `Dispatch<T>` call.  You'd still preserve the type checking, and avoid the need to manually check for handling.

Comment: By re-introducing `CanHandle` we are back at square one: Should `Handle` assume that the client called `CanHandle` or not?

Comment: Not really - with this setup, `CanHandle` doesn't need to be exposed to the client at all.

Comment: `CommandManager` *is* the client.